# Different URL path for Visual Studio and IIS

Tags: jquery, url, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

How to set a URL in vanilla JavaScript or with jQuery when I deploy an application in IIS?

In Visual Studio, this URL works (without path):

```
url: '/street/details/'
```

But IIS needs this URL:

```
url: '**/utca**/street/details/'.
```

I woukd like to modify the URLs in every JavaScript file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `asp.net-mvc-5` then you shouldn't be using *any* hardcoded paths.

You should be using `@Html.Action` or `@Url.Action` or equivalents.  This allows you to move things at will / per-environment.

If you really must use paths directly, eg in a .js file where you can't use server-side and don't want to go to the hassle of passing the url either as a parameter or as a `data-` attribute, the easiest method is to set up a global (or namespaced) variable to your root path, eg place this at the `<head>` of your `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var mynamespace = mynamespace || {}; 
    mynamespace.rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

then your script can use this whereever needed, eg:

```
$.ajax({
    url: mynamespace.rootPath + 'street/details/',
```

Comment: Thank you. I hoped there was any support to simplify it in VS.